# Is it necessary that the chapter introduction be made up of just one paragraph?

Tags: research-process, thesis, writing

In writing the introduction of a chapter, I came up with three paragraphs.

Is it necessary that the chapter introduction be made up of just one paragraph?

Comment: The question assumes that there is a single uniform global standard for writing such introductions. No, there is not. Ask people in your university about local customs and follow their guidelines.

Comment: I can't image any research community that would impose such rigid formatting styles.  If it takes three paragraphs to introduce the chapter, use three paragraphs.  If it takes one sentence, use one sentence.

Comment: Agree with @DmitrySavostyanov . Content should whenever possible take priority over format. I would imagine word-count is more likely to be limited by standards than paragraph-count. Whatever the case, use all the space needed to get your point across, but try to write economically. Best bet in your case seems to be talking to the publisher or consulting the appropriate FAQ webpage.

Comment: What makes you think that you should limit your introduction to a single paragraph?

Comment: A deep-seated habit of thinking of the introduction as a single first paragraph.

Comment: A hint in hindsight: Tell us which kind of text you are writing, as the answer might depend on it – though in this case it does not (or at least should not).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to limit your chapter introductions to one paragraph (unless your university has some ridiculous formatting guidelines that require this).

Comment: At Hogwarts they teach a spell against that, actually.