# Is it okay to begin a chapter without an "introduction section"?

Tags: thesis, writing-style, latex

I'm writing my phd thesis. In some chapters I simply begin the chapter with one or maybe two (at most) paragraphs that mostly gives the outline, and then I begin the sectioning. That is, this paragraph has no section, the sections start right afterwards. I'm wondering if this is normal and acceptable or should I put it in a separate section?

This is how it looks in latex:

```
\chapter{System Modeling}

A paragraph giving the outline of this chapter. Section ?? discusses this and that. ....

\section{Equation of Motion} %this is the first section of this chapter
```

Comment: Were you given style guide when you started your thesis? Did you ask your advisor this question?

Comment: In my University this is quite common to do, but like commented by @scaaahu I would ask first if there is a style guide.

Comment: there is unfortunately no style guide.

Comment: What did your advisor say? You do have an advisor, don't you?

Comment: Related question: [Is it necessary that the the chapter introduction be made up of just one paragraph?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/24250/546)

Comment: i don't think it is the same question. They ask about the introduction "chapter". Here I'm talking about an introduction "section" in a chapter

Comment: Please read the first line of the linked question _In writing the introduction of a chapter_ and I did not say this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

In general, sections should be organized to create a chapter just like subsections are organized to create a section and subsubsection should be organized to create a subsection.  In other words, the important unit is the largest one, and the smaller elements (sections, subsections, etc.) are used only the assist and guide the reader in their understanding of a large chunk of narrative.

As such, I would consider it the normal and *preferred* case to begin a chapter with prose, setting forth an introduction to the chapter before the first section heading.  In fact, a particularly short chapter might have no section headings at all, as it is a good rule of thumb to note use any textual subdivision until you need two of them (e.g., don't divide a chapter into one section, or a section into one subsection).