# What are advantages and disadvantages of "chapter abstracts"

Tags: thesis, grading, formatting

What are advantages and disadvantages (totally not implying that there is a rule) of "chapter abstracts", i.e., short summaries of the content of the following chapter, which are placed directly below the chapter heading and not as part of a subchapter.

The side against them often claims that it is not allowed to place text outside of the rigid chapter-subchapter strucure (see, e.g., https://www.christianlehmann.eu/ling/epistemology/techniques/redaction/index.html?https://www.christianlehmann.eu/ling/epistemology/techniques/redaction/aufbau_wiss_arbeit.php due to a lack of a better source, a website from a Professor emeritus for General and Comparative Linguistics from University of Erfurt, Germany).

The other side often perceives a universal need for everything to be introduced, sometimes going as far as claiming that no heading and subheading should be placed directly next to each other (see, e.g., https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/crea-lit/headings-and-subheadings), which would mean that even for a third-level heading consisting of fourth-level subheadings one would need to write a "chapter abstract".

While I am still looking for the perfect word for "chapter abstract", I would like to hear advantages and disadvantages of "chapter abstracts" (preferably based on credible/authorative sources, to eliminate the suspicion of soliticing "opinions").

A disadvantage that I see is the following: A chapter's and its subchapters' headings should speak for themselves and show a clear "guiding thread". Chapter abstracts seem to absolve the student of any necessity for finding headings that mean something and ordering them so that a guiding thread is obvious, since they will just add a short "clarification" of what follows at the beginning of a chapter.

Comment: Why do you think a general or universal rule is needed? Shouldn't it be dependent on the work itself?

Comment: I don't think a universal rule is needed or exists, particularly one in favour of "chapter abstracts", which is why I am asking for "arguments for and against" in the title! And yes, it is dependent on the work itself, which is why I specified "bachelor's and master's thesis", which are somewhat comparable (with regards to the question of chapter abstracts) among all disciplines.

Comment: I agree with Buffy that this depends on the work itself, and by this I mean *on an individual level*. I see no reason why, say, two Master's theses in mathematics should follow the same "rule" here.In fact, I see no need for a rule at all. It might even be different for two chapters within the same thesis in some cases.

Comment: I rarely flag as "opinion-based" but I've done so for this question as it seems to be soliciting opinions. I think this is an interesting discussion topic, but the SE philosophy is that this precise venue is not a discussion forum.

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure what you mean by an "authorative source". If the "Hogwarts style guide to mumbo jumbo writing" says that one should always do A and B, what does this tell us except that some people, presumably in Hogwarts, wrote a style guide and came to some agreement that they should suggest A and B in this guide (it does not even mean that all the authors of the guide necessarily share this specific point of view regarding A and B).

Comment: I have never heard anyone argue that anyone cannot put text before the first subsection.  Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @TerryLoring, Sometimes we just have not dealt with a topic in sufficient detail. Therefore, please see my edit; you'll find a source including a well-substantiated justification for the given opinion, which is unfortunately lacking in this comment section thus far.

Comment: @AnonymousM Fair point, this question asks for opinions. However, I think it is a fact that there are two sides with very differing opinions on this matter. This is exactly the reason I was asking this question, to get an overview of the arguments of the different sides, including of course justification for claims and preferably with "authorative sources".

Comment: @JochenGlueck, Well, it is ok if you see no reason for this or anything else; everyone is entitled to their opinion. It would be, however, advantageous to your argument if you laid out how you came to this conclusion by giving some justification. Ideally, you would substantiate your claim with an "authorative source".

Comment: I have to accept the pecking order here, but sometimes it seems that if people don't know a good answer, they are very quick to assume that the question is the problem. For anyone interested in answering or an answer to the question, it was asked here before and an opinion was given: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63162/is-it-okay-to-begin-a-chapter-without-an-introduction-section?rq=1

Comment: @SebastianE: "*It would be, however, advantageous to your argument if you laid out how you came to this conclusion by giving some justification*" Sorry, but you got it backwards here: Your question seems to suggest that there should be some rule about whether to use chapter abstracts. But if you want to restrict people's choices (or suggest that they restrict their choices themselves) by suggesting some general rule, then the burden to argue for the need of such a rule is on *you*. There is no such argument in your question, though. [...]

Comment: [...] (The first link contains a brief argument against chapter abstracts, but clearly looks at the topic from a very field-dependent perspective; the second link claims that one should use chapter abstracts, but does not give any justification; your last paragraph discusses a point which you consider a disavdantage of chapter abstracts, but does not explain why this should result in a general rule against chapter abstracts rather than in a case-by-case decision).

Comment: By the way, if you asked for a list of advantages and disadvantages of chapter abstracts (which could then be used to inform individual decisions on a case-by-case basis) rather than for opinions for or against the "necessity" of chapter abstracts, then I think this question would be both on topic and very interesting.

Comment: @JochenGlueck (1.) My question does not suggest there should be a rule, so your whole "you got it backwards here" argument is kinda pointless. (2.) It's not a field-dependent perspective to suggest that it doesn't make sense since you can't reference it, that's an absolutely general/universal "disadvantage". (3.) Yes, my second link doesn't give any justification for the "rule"; I don't make the argument there is a rule, I make the argument that two sides exist. (4.) I repeat myself a third time, I didn't derive a rule since I don't think there is one, I just gave "disadvantages" that I see.

Comment: @JochenGlueck There is not really a difference between asking about "arguments for and against" and "benefits and advantages of" something. Anyways, I have now removed any potential for anyone to claim that "you are implying a rule here, buddy".

Comment: @SebastianE: Thanks for your response! I think what made me perceive the question as to categorial was the wording "The side against them" and "In students paper's, I am against it", along with two references which do indeed suggest a general rule (though in opposite directions). But, after your edits and comments, I understand that you are indeed rather looking for advantages and disadvantages. I upvoted your question and voted to reopen it since, as I said before, I think this is a very interesting and useful question.

Comment: Regarding point (2), here is why a find the argument field dependend: the argument might make sense for disciplines which typically refer to specific parts of long texts, such as linguistics (but I am not a linguist; so I wrote "might make sense" rather than "makes sense", as I do not feel entitled to a strong opinion here). For mathematical documents, though, the suggestion doesn't make much sense since it is extremelly common in mathematics to enumerate mathematicals definitions, results, remarks, and so on, and then refer explicitly to this number. [...]

Comment: [...] I can think of only very rare situations where a mathematician would like to explicitly refer to the content of a chapter abstract, but cannot do so due to the abstract not having its own section number.

Answer (score 1):

Style issues depend on the specific audience. You will need to check with the place you want to publish your document. They will have preferences. Their preferences  may be different from those of other groups, and possibly will change over time.

Check if there is a style guide and if so, try to follow it. There may not be a formal style guide. Look at the documents of similar type that have recently been published in the same place and find out how they have been formatted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am asking for "advantages and disadvantages" about chapter abstracts (in bachelor's and master's thesis from the supervisor side).